# Using a custom registry in a camel application

Tags: apache-camel

I am in the process of implementing a generic message router. My message router should be able to work with different JMS and database resources configured at run time.

I had no problems with JMS as I could dynamically create and add `JmsComponent` instances at run time.

My problem is with adding data sources. I was able to create them from java code, decorate them with transaction manager test that they actually get are able to connect, etc. However I got stuck with adding them to the registry so a `jdbc:myDataSource` endpoint will resolve properly.

A bit out of ideas and with google taking me nowhere I tried to implement a custom `Registry` that would accept a `registerBean(String key, Object bean)` method. To minimize the work I done this by extending the camel out of the box `CompositeRegistry` like below.

```
/**
 * Custom implementation of a camel registry to facilitate
 * adding beans at run time..
 */
public class MessageRouterRegistry implements Registry {
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext messageRouterContext;

    private Registry springContextRegistry;
    private final SimpleRegistry simpleRegistry;

    public MessageRouterRegistry() {
        simpleRegistry = new SimpleRegistry();
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void initSpringRegistry() {
        springContextRegistry = new ApplicationContextRegistry(messageRouterContext);
    }

    public void registerBean(String key, Object bean) {
        simpleRegistry.put(key, bean);
    }

    @Override
    public Object lookupByName(String name) {
        return  new CompositeRegistry(asList(simpleRegistry, springContextRegistry)).lookupByName(name);
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T lookupByNameAndType(String name, Class<T> type) {
        return new CompositeRegistry(asList(simpleRegistry, springContextRegistry)).lookupByNameAndType(name, type);
    }

    // The other methods follow the same pattern
}
```

I also have an unit test (Test-NG) that does not do anything else than to wire all spring application context and check the beans are all accessible.

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:META-INF/spring/camel-context.xml"})
@TestExecutionListeners(CustomTestExecutionListener.class)
public class CamelContextStartupTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {

    @Test
    public void shouldBeAbleToLoadCamelContext() throws Exception {
        assertThat(applicationContext.getBean("message-router"), instanceOf(CamelContext.class));
    }
}
```

This test runs OK and I can see in the logs all routes being created properly. Note the custom test listener does not do anything else than to set some expected system properties before anything else happens.

However when i run the right thing which is pretty much loading the same spring context file I got this exception below:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'message-router': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@cecf639 has not been refreshed yet
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at au.com.nab.message.router.running.RouterRunner.createApplicationContext(RouterRunner.java:25)
    at au.com.nab.message.router.running.RouterRunner.start(RouterRunner.java:38)
    at au.com.nab.message.router.running.RouterRunner.main(RouterRunner.java:18)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@cecf639 has not been refreshed yet
```

My gut feeling is that obviously I am not doing something right but I cannot spot what. The exception message is quiet clear; I am trying to access beans from context when they are not ready to use but I cannot find a way to fix this and maybe is not fixable as my approach is wrong.

So here are my questions:

1. Any way to add beans to the registry at run time?
2. How is a custom registry supposed to work or is there a better way to get a reference of the spring application context before start using it?
3. Was CompositeRegistry class created for some sort of camel internal usage or is was it designed for public usage. I know it is public but its most interesting method `getRegistryList` is package scope.

Thank you in advance for your inputs.

Comment: Did you solve this? Did you define your MessageRouterRegistry as a bean in Spring XML? See: [Camel Context Configuration](http://camel.apache.org/advanced-configuration-of-camelcontext-using-spring.html)

Comment: Yes I did. And it works fine so far in my tests. I have not published my answer yet as I wanted it more testing but I'll try to answer it today when I find a bit of time. In short I gave up using the `CompositeRegistry` from camel and used a `JndiRegistry` instead. Then I let a `BeanFactoryPostProcessoer` and a 'BeanPostProcessor` from spring populate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I managed to get a custom registry working in my camel application and make it possible to bind beans at run time. This solution has a bit of complexity and I do believe it would be great if camel framework will natively add a `registerBean(String key, Object bean)` method to their `Registry` interface.

```
/**
 * Custom implementation of a camel registry to facilitate
 * adding beans at run time. Nothing else then a wrapper
 * around a camel SimpleRegistry instance.
 */
public class MessageRouterRegistry implements Registry {

    private final SimpleRegistry simpleRegistry;

    public MessageRouterRegistry() {
        simpleRegistry = new SimpleRegistry();
        REGISTRY.setRegistry(this);
    }

    public void registerBean(String key, Object bean) {
        simpleRegistry.put(key, bean);
    }

    @Override
    public Object lookupByName(String beanName) {
        return  simpleRegistry.lookupByName(beanName);
    }
    // All the other methods follow the same delefdate pattern
    ...
}
```

The only thing to notice in the above `Registry` implementation is that after constructing is done the registry register itself with a `REGISTRY` singleton. As you will see later this was needed to get hold of this `Registry` instance before the camel context is being fully created. The singleton implementation is just a simple enum.

```
/**
 * Message Router Registry holder. 
 */
public enum RegistryHolderSingleton {
    REGISTRY;

    private MessageRouterRegistry registry;

    public void setRegistry(MessageRouterRegistry registry) {
        this.registry = registry;
    }

    public void registerBean(String beanName, Object bean) {
        registry.registerBean(beanName, bean);
    }
}
```

To make use of the custom registry in the camel-context.xml I added the entries below. Note the two `PostProcessor` beans that will actually do the trick.

```
<camel:camelContext id="message-router">
    <camel:propertyPlaceholder location="router.properties" id="router.properties"/>
    <camel:routeBuilder ref="routesBuilder"/>
</camel:camelContext>

<bean id="routerRegistry" class="au.com.nab.message.router.registry.MessageRouterRegistry"/>
<bean class="au.com.nab.message.router.registry.RouterBeanFactoryPostProcessor"/>
<bean class="au.com.nab.message.router.registry.RouterBeanPostProcessor"/>
```

The RouterBeanFactoryPostProcessor is used to hack the spring application context and make sure my custom `MessageRouterRegistry`is the first bean to instantiate by changing all bean definitions to depend on this one. I could have just called `beanFactory.getBean(ROUTER_REGISTRY)` but this is against spring recommendations to not instantiate beans in the bean factory post processor so this is how I ended up with this rather unusual implementation. However calling `getBean(...)` worked for me with no apparent side effects.

```
/**
 * Custom bean factory post processor to facilitate instantiating
 * router registry bean before any other beans.
 */
public class RouterBeanFactoryPostProcessor implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor {

    private static final String ROUTER_REGISTRY = "routerRegistry";

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory)
            throws BeansException {
        // For most of the beans (see rules below) alter their definition
        // so they will be instantiated after the "routerRegistry" bean 
        for (String beanName : beanFactory.getBeanDefinitionNames()) {
            BeanDefinition beanDefinition = beanFactory.getBeanDefinition(beanName);
            if (okToSetAsDependant(beanDefinition)) {
                beanDefinition.setDependsOn(ROUTER_REGISTRY);
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean okToSetAsDependant(BeanDefinition beanDefinition) {
         // Do not set the bean dependency if:
         // 1. An internal Spring used bean
         // 2. Is an instance of this post processor class as this is already created
         // 3. Is our custom message router registry as this is the one we want to create first
         // 4. Has dependencies defined already as these ones will not be created first anyway
         return !((beanDefinition instanceof RootBeanDefinition)
                 || beanDefinition.getBeanClassName().equals(getClass().getName())
                 || beanDefinition.getBeanClassName().equals(MessageRouterRegistry.class.getName())
                 || beanDefinition.getDependsOn() != null);
    }
}
```

And finally RouterBeanPostProcessor will register every single spring bean with the custom `Registry`

```
/**
 * Custom bean post processor to put all spring beans into the
 * custom camel registry.
 */
public class RouterBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {
    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        if (!(bean instanceof MessageRouterRegistry)) {
            REGISTRY.registerBean(beanName, bean);
        }
        return bean;
    }
}
```

Once this was done I was able to add beans in my custom `Registry` at run time. One more thing to be aware of is that camel will also wrap your custom registry within a `PropertyPlaceholderDelegateRegistry` instance so to access your custom registry you will either make a not so nice cast in your code or get it from the singleton instance.

At the time of publishing this the code in this answer works fine in all my unit tests and so far in pre-prod test environments but is not as yet fully tested and considered production ready.

Hope you will find this useful as googling for a how to solution took me close to nowhere.

Comment: You my friend, probably, is going to save my life! I am trying this right away.